# is it possible to append file name version at the end of a file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I often see on website the file name ends with ?(version) a version number like so

```
/static/fav/fav.ico?2
```

same applied to css or js files

```
/static/css/d.css?2
```

is it possible to append this ? then the version of the file with webpack ? or how do people do such a thing

Answer (score 2):

People do this because photo files, css and js are cached in web browsers. Browsers remember these files to reload pages faster.

However, if you make a change to the example.js file and want to force the browser to reload it instead of the cached file - you declare it with a different filename, e.g. example.js?v=2

Comment: thank you for your answer, i don't think people rename the files manually it must be automated isn't it ?